# Launching camera intent from onCreate or onCreateView in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm developing an Android application that uses a `Fragment` that will launch the camera with an `Intent` to capture an image and then the fragment also contains some `EditText`'s for the user to fill in when the `Intent` returns.

I wonder what the best place (best practice) to launch the intent is? Is it in the `onCreate()` or the `onCreateView()` method that are both overridden?

Comment: IMHO, a fragment should not be starting an activity from either `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`. A fragment should only be starting an activity based upon the positive action of a user (e.g., clicking an action bar item, clicking a button).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will gladly do it this way. Just to make it clear though, the user has already pressed a button labeled "Add" which launches another activity and fetches the fragment. I think it would be ok to launch the Camera from the Fragment (at least I don't think the user would be too confused).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) stated in the first comment a fragment should not be starting an `Activity` from neither of `onCreate` nor `onCreateView`. His argument was that since the user didn't press a button, no action should be taken. In my design however, an `"Add"` button had been pressed that then launched the fragment which I wanted to automatically launch the camera intent. My reason for doing this was to force the user into first take a picture since my application requires a picture to work. The user would then fill out some other fields and save the data.

I realize now that [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) was right. It is better to let the user click another button then to surprise them into something they didn't expect. I also realized that it is a good idea to let the user see what fields are required in the form before forcing the user to take an action.

I ended up adding an `ImageButton` with the camera icon to launch the intent and it's working great.